# Github pages homepage remove link at the top

Tags: github, github-pages

I created my own website using GitHub Pages [here](https://imrankhan17.github.io/).

However the homepage has a big hyperlink at the top which isn't included in the Markdown.  It also doesn't appear in the README.md file [here](https://github.com/imrankhan17/imrankhan17.github.io).

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is included because it's actually serving the readme file. Can you serve an HTML file instead? You can use a [Markdown to HTML convertor](https://dillinger.io/).

Try dropping your markdown into the link above, and pasting the HTML output into a new file named `index.html` in your repo.

Comment: This worked but I'd really like to keep the Markdown styling.

Comment: You can export the markdown with styling from that site. There's not really any other way around it. If you display a .md file that banner will always be there.

Comment: You could grab the html from that page, remove the banner and use it instead.

Answer (score 6):

In your `_config.yml` add `title: <your title>`. If `<your title>` is equal to your page title, it won't show the hyperlink.

Ref: https://github.com/pages-themes/primer/blob/master/_layouts/default.html

Comment: Underrated answer, thanks

Comment: Solved the issue for me! It might take ~2-3 minutes and a refresh to see the change.